# Decrease loss in keras training using lstm

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, training-data

I have an input like this:

```python
x_train = [
    [0,0,0,1,-1,-1,1,0,1,0,...,0,1,-1],
    [-1,0,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,...,-1,-1,0],
    ...
    [1,0,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,...,-1,-1,0]
]
```

which `1` means increase in one metric and `-1` means decrease in it and `0` means no change in the metric. Each array has 83 items for 83 fields and the output (labels) for each array is a categorical array that shows effect of these metrics on a single metric:

```python
[[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.],
 [ 0.  0.  1.],
 ...
 [ 0.  0.  1.],
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

I used `keras` and `lstm` in the following code:

```python
def train(x, y, x_test, y_test):
    x_train = np.array(x)
    y_train = np.array(y)
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 3)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(x_train.shape[0], output_dim=256))
    model.add(LSTM(128))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    opt = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=opt,
            metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=100)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 3)
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
    prediction = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=128)
    print score
    print prediction
```

but the loss after 100 epochs is:

`1618/1618 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.7328 - acc: 0.5556`

How can I decrease this loss percentage?

Comment: Why are you using embedding layer?

Comment: @djk47463 I am new to training models. I read some articles and some blogs and write this code. What should I do for the best result?

Comment: I wouldn't use and embedding layer, with is typically used for word vectors

Comment: @djk47463 Thanks. You mean that i remove that line?

Comment: yes, and add and `input_shape` to the lstm

Comment: @djk47463 Thanks, i add `LSTM(128, input_shape=(3, 256))` but i get error `Error when checking model input: expected lstm_input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1618, 83)`

Comment: Is your data time series data?

Comment: @djk47463 each array in the `x_train` is for a specific time(each of them represents one day). Also, each item in the `y_array` is for the same time.